# Why Laravel provides default timestamps?

Tags: php, laravel-5.6, laravel-5.7

When we create a new Model or database migration in Laravel we can use `$table->timestamps();` which creates `created_at` and `updated_at` by default. Why does a project required these fields in the view of a best project structure?

Answer (score 2):

It's always useful to know when an object is created or updated. Even though I personally prefer creating different timestamps for different purposes, like if I have an entity which gets processed asynchronously, I usually add a datetime column called `completed_at` so that I know when the job was completed.

If you don't like default timestamps, you can remove them by assigning public $timestamps = false; in your Eloquent model.

Answer (score 2):

Every `Model/Records` you insert in table it`s better to track its `created_at` time and `updated_at` time. `Timestamp` use cases could be different depending upon indiviusal.

Most developer use timepstamp to track their database records.

That`s why Laravel Eloquent by default provide `created_at` and `updated_at` options. Whenever Model/Records get created `created_at` column value get set automatically and whenever record get updated `updated_at` column value set to that time automatically, so developer need to write minimum code for managing timestamps.

Laravel timestamps are optional use `public $timestamps = false;` in Model to disable timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

`create_at` and `updated_at` is very useful when there's multiple roles in your system. In my project i have multiple roles so i have added columns like `updated_by` and `created_by` with laravel's `created_at` and `updated_at` i can find on which date and time it's created OR updated and by my columns `created_at` and `updated_at` i can find out `which user created record` and `which user updated` record.

Also laravel timestamp `automatically update` the record column at the time of update so you don't need to worry about it to write code for change the `update_at` column in table.

So basically for `tracing` the `timestamp` is very useful in your project.

If you don't need it in every table then you can simply avoid it using below line in you model.

`public $timestamps = false;`