# getting null value at created_at laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

There a blog create and post functionality in my project.When I create a post I am getting date at created_at field is Jan 01 1970. When I tried to debug it,got null value for this field.I am unable to figure it out.

blog.blade.php

```
     @foreach($blogs as $blog)
              <div class="blog-container">
              <div class="blog-info">
         <h3><a href="https://africainnovationmarket.org/blog/testing-blog-by-acropolis-11/" title="Testing Blog by Acropolis 11" rel="bookmark">{{$blog->name}}</a></h3>                 <div class="created-blog-info">
                       <div class="create-time"><?php echo date("M d Y",strtotime($blog->created_at));
                       echo $blog->created_at;
                       ?> </div>
                       <?php $name = DB::table('userdetails')->where('id',$blog->created_by)->get();   ?>
                       <div class="create-author">@if($blog->created_by > 0 ) {{$name[0]->firstname}} {{$name[0]->lastname}} @else Admin @endif</div>
                       <div class="sharelinks" style="float:right"></div>
                 </div>
               

            @endforeach
```

BlogController.php

```
   public function blog()
    {
        $blogs = DB::table('blogs')->where('delete_status','0')->get();
        return view("home.blog",compact("blogs"));
    }
```

This is my blog table structure

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `blogs` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `content` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `tags` varchar(55) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `delete_status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

when I create a blog, created_at field should take that date so that I can get exact value of created_at field instead of null.How should I do it?

Comment: user laravel model so auto generate `created_at` or else u need to manually insert in to db via `query builder`

Comment: Want to auto generate, when someone created a blog,this date should be displayed there.

Comment: then use laravel model to insert data

Comment: This is my blog table structure

Comment: @V.R.K Don't you use Eloquent models?

Comment: Have a look at [Why Laravel provides default timestamps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54073010/why-laravel-provides-default-timestamps)

Comment: solved this issue by changing default value of created_at from NULL to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()

Answer (score 1):

use `now()` while insert the data  ref link https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#method-now

```php
DB::table('blogs')->insert([
    'created_at' => now(), //now is a helper function in laravel  
    'updated_at' => now(),
]);
```

or

```php
Blog::create() // it will automatically create both
```

Comment: In blog.balde.php file <?php echo date("M d Y",strtotime($blog->created_at)); want when I create a blog,the date on which this blog was created displayed here.ie should be fetched from database created_at field and displayed here,since I am printing it here.

Comment: have u checked in your database `created_at` is empty or any data is there .?

Comment: so while insert post to `blogs` table use my code mention in above and delete old record

Answer (score 0):

If you create a blog model this would be done by Laravel automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `created_at` value as `null` because you did not insert it. Because you did not use a model, you have to insert it manually or you can make a model.

Manually,

```
DB::table('blogs')->insert(['created_at'= > now()]);
```

For unix timestamp use `now()->timestamp`
Or make a model,

```
php artisan make:model Blog
```

It will create a model. Then You have to create a blog.

```
Blog::create([]);
```

By `create()` method it will insert `created_at`, `updated_at` value autometically.